# Advanced boostrap 3 column ordering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I achieve this layout in bootstrap 3. I have tried pulling & pushing but this one is doing my head in, Thanks.

**xs = 1 col (col-xs-12):**

AAA

BBB

CCC

DDD

EEE

FFF

GGG

**sm = 2 col (col-sm-6):**

AAA | EEE

BBB | FFF

CCC | GGG

DDD

**md = 3 col (col-md-4):**

AAA | DDD  | GGG

BBB | EEE

CCC | FFF

**lg = 4 col (col-lg-3):**

AAA | CCC | EEE  | GGG

BBB | DDD | FFF

http://www.bootply.com/16d9SFyDGD

Comment: Maybe try [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional col sizes to adjust at different screen resolutions.

The col-xs is for smaller screen sizes, so if you are viewing on a laptop screen or desktop you will not see the desired effect.

I think the below will help, but you may need to adjust the numbers to get the desired effects you want. The col-sizes I used view fine  horizontally in your example from bootply.com you provided.

You can review the bootstrap documentation for the grid layout classes [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) to get a more in-depth explanation and see additional examples.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">AAA</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">BBB</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">CCC</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">DDD</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">EEE</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">FFF</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">GGG</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are aiming at cannot be achieved by pushing or pulling.

If at least the same elements appeared in each resolution tier but in different orders, it might be possible, but the wrapping you are searching for cannot be done.

The only scenario I could think of is playing with negative top-bottom margins or positioning elements absolutely but this would require for all elements to have the same dimensions to avoid unwanted wrapping or overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to use CSS multi-columns since the **natural flow is top-to-bottom** and then left-to-right.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row.sp {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .row.sp {
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .row.sp {
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/br3073C2JJ